# How to extend WebTestCase in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to write functional tests in symfony but I am unable to over-ride `createKernel` method of WebTestCase. Our application integrated symfony by using an HttpKernel like this :

```
$kernel = new HttpKernel($dispatcher, $controllerResolver, new 
RequestStack(), $argumentResolver);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I tried returning this kernel from over-ridden `createKernel` method but it doesn't have some methods(like `getContainer()` ) which gives error later on. How can I create my own kernel for WebTestCase?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here, but if you extend `WebTestCase` you have access to `static::bootKernel()` which will boot your Kernel and you will have access to container with `getContainer`.

Comment: If I run my test case file using ./vendor/bin/phpunit , I get the error "Unable to guess Kernel directory". Symfony docs specify that "WebTestCase class needs to know which is the application kernel to bootstrap it". Since the only kernel I have in my whole app is HttpKernel, I am not sure what else can I do apart from writing my own new Kernel. This is where I need help as to how to write my own kernel.

Comment: Does your Kernel extend `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel` ?

Comment: No. I use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel namespace above in my file.

Comment: you can set env variable `KERNEL_DIR` and then WebTestCase will find your Kernel class

Comment: @DenisAlimov where should I set KERNEL_DIR ? And what should be it's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see documentation [testing (symfony docs)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#your-first-functional-test)

> To run your functional tests, the WebTestCase class needs to know
>   which is the application kernel to bootstrap it. The kernel class is
>   usually defined in the KERNEL_CLASS environment variable (included in
>   the default phpunit.xml.dist file provided by Symfony):

```
<?xml version="1.0" charset="utf-8" ?>
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <!-- the value is the FQCN of the application kernel -->
        <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />
    </php>
    <!-- ... -->
</phpunit>
```

Also, you have phpunit runnable in your bin directory and phpunit.xml.dist file in app directory. usually you can run tests by `bin/phpunit -c app path_to_the_tests`

Comment: I don't have any phpuniti.xml.dist file present in my project. My project is being migrated to symfony, it was not written from scratch in symfony(hence not present by default). Also I don't have any App folder.

Comment: create phpunit.xml in some folder. and call phpunit with `-c thatfolder`